# Metal shader in SceneKit to outline an object

Tags: ios, shader, scenekit, metal, fragment-shader

I'm playing around and trying to implement Metal shader in SceneKit that will outline an object.

The idea is to draw an outline (or silhouette) similar to this image found in [this blogpost](http://dansgamedev.blogspot.com/2011/03/) (the blogpost doesn't contain any code):

[image: silhouette]

I'm new to SceneKit and Metal shaders so I'm able just to draw some geometry and write simple vertex or fragment shader. I'm curious how can I achieve this kind of effect? Is it done in multiple passes?

Cheers!

Comment: That's more than a silhouette. That looks more like some form of "edge detection", which is a term you can search for to find lots of info.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The basic idea here is to clone the "selected" node and its geometry, then use a custom vertex and fragment shader to "push" the geometry out along the vertex normals, drawing only the back faces of the cloned geometry with a solid color.

I wrote a small sample project to demonstrate this and posted it [here](https://github.com/warrenm/SCNOutline).

The core Swift code looks like this:

```
let outlineProgram = SCNProgram()
outlineProgram.vertexFunctionName = "outline_vertex"
outlineProgram.fragmentFunctionName = "outline_fragment"

let outlineNode = duplicateNode(node)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(outlineNode)
outlineNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.program = outlineProgram
outlineNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.cullMode = .front
```

The portion of the vertex shader responsible for pushing vertices along their normal looks like this:

```
const float extrusionMagnitude = 0.05;
float3 modelPosition = in.position + normalize(in.normal) * extrusionMagnitude;
```

From there, you just apply your typical model-view-projection matrix and return a flat color from the fragment shader.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's why I love SO. You can always find people happy to help! My original idea was to do something similar with fragment shader, modifying fragment color based on normal but this approach looks interesting. Will post another question if needed. Thank you again.

Comment: I'm concerned how to do it without cloning model. I run into this tutorial: http://in2gpu.com/2014/06/23/toon-shading-effect-and-simple-contour-detection/ but I'm struggling with rewriting it to Metal. Do you mind if I send you project with my implementation of toon shading? Have you got a time to check what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a separate question. Also, your project link gives a 404 error.

Comment: Good point. I created another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658843/implementing-toon-effect-with-metal-shader-and-scenekit