# Implementing toon effect with Metal shader and SceneKit

Tags: shader, scenekit, metal, fragment-shader

I would like to improve my recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53394751/metal-shader-in-scenekit-to-outline-an-object/53403480) and implement toon effect [like this](http://in2gpu.com/2014/06/23/toon-shading-effect-and-simple-contour-detection/) using Metal (fragment) shader in SceneKit.

Here is my fragment shader implementing both simple phong lighting and toon effect:

```
fragment float4 lightingFragment(VertexOut in [[stage_in]]) {

    float3 normal = normalize(in.normal);

    // For edges set color to yellow
    float3 V = normalize(in.eye - in.position.xyz);
    float edgeDetection = (abs(dot(V, normal)) > 0.1) ? 1 : 0;
    if ( edgeDetection != 1 ) {
        return float4(1, 1, 0, 1);
    }

    // Compute simple phong
    float3 lightDirection = normalize(light.position - in.position.xyz);
    float diffuseIntensity = saturate(dot(normal, lightDirection));
    float3 diffuseTerm = light.diffuseColor * material.diffuseColor * diffuseIntensity;

    // Ambient color
    float3 ambientTerm = light.ambientColor * material.ambientColor;

    return float4(ambientTerm + diffuseTerm, 1.0);
}
```

As I said I go inspired by [this article](http://in2gpu.com/2014/06/23/toon-shading-effect-and-simple-contour-detection/) but I get very different result...

[image]

Any ideas? Here is the [whole project](https://github.com/martinpilch/toon-shading-example)

Comment: I updated the GitHub project based on suggestions from Warren: https://github.com/martinpilch/toon-shading-example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of single-pass view-space technique is necessarily going to produce worse results than the normal-extrusion technique, but in order for it to work at all, you need to get a grip on your coordinate spaces.

What's the aim here? Well, we want to notice when the surface normal is *nearly perpendicular* to the view direction, and bypass our usual lighting calculations, returning a solid silhouette color instead.

Determining perpendicularity usually means taking dot products, but in (a +Y up, right-handed) view space, the view direction is just (0, 0, -1), `V` is just (0, 0, 1), and the dot product between V and the view-space normal is just the `z` component of the view-space normal.

With that knowledge in-hand, we just need to make sure we're passing the view-space normal to our fragment shader correctly.

First, change the name of the normal we pass out from the vertex shader to `eyeNormal` so we're clear on what space we're operating in. It's then computed as

```
out.eyeNormal = (scn_node.modelViewTransform * float4(in.normal, 0)).xyz;
```

(where we're making the usual glib assumption that the MV matrix doesn't contain any nonuniform scaling or shearing). Normalize as usual in the fragment shader:

```
float3 normal = normalize(in.eyeNormal);
```

Get rid of that ternary garbage; a boolean expression has boolean type, which coerces just fine into a `float`:

```
float edgeFactor = normal.z <= 0.3;
```

Note that because we're operating in view space, we won't actually see any fragments that have `normal.z < 0`, so we drop the `abs` too.

Finally, since we won't actually save any cycles with that early exit, we can use the `mix` function to select between the lit color and the edge color as we return:

```
return mix(float4(ambientTerm + diffuseTerm, 1.0), float4(1, 1, 0, 1), edgeFactor);
```

And there you have it, cruddy silhouettes for half the price:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks Warren! I really appreciate it. Rendering is just small part of side project I'm working on that's why I've got these basic questions. I guess I will post more in near future. Thanks again!

Comment: I created another question going more into details of my project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53764324/render-horizon-silhouette-using-metal-in-scenekit